# theorem: subspaces of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following theorem has been stated in a Linear Algebra book(by A.R. Rao and P. Bhimasankaram)

> The subspaces of $\mathbb{R^2}$ are $\lbrace 0\rbrace$, the lines through the origin and $\mathbb{R^2}$ itself.
>   The subspaces of $\mathbb{R^3}$ are $\lbrace 0\rbrace$, the lines through the origin, the planes through the origin and $\mathbb{R^3}$ itself.

What I am unable to understand is why $\lbrace 0\rbrace$ was specifically mentioned, when it is supposed to come under $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$ themselves(because these stand for all the points in them and not lines or planes).

Also, why must the lines and planes pass through the origin?

I am  not exactly through with the geometric meaning of linear combination, subspaces and span w.r.t. this theorem/example. Please, explain?

Comment: $\{0\}$ is a vector subspace, since it is closed under addition $(0 + 0 = 0)$ and scalar multiplication ($\lambda 0 = 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Joppy Basically, {0} as the zero vector is a vector subspace in itself and also as a part of $\mathbb{R^2}$ or $\mathbb{R^3}$, right?

Comment: To get a geometric idea of linear combination, you may see

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110424/geometrically-describing-linear-combinations

Comment: Also, once you get geometric idea, try to answer why any line which does not pass through origin cannot be a subspace?

Comment: The first $0$ is $(0,0)$ and the second $0$ is $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh the lines and planes are subspaces. By defn., they are supposed to pass through the origin. Is that right?

Comment: @ZaIra yes. That is how it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a linear space or vector space $\mathbf{R}^2$ has dimension $2$ and $\mathbf{R}^3$ has dimension 3. So, all possible subspaces of $\mathbf{R}^2$ can be of dimension $0, 1$ and $2$. Hence are $\{0\}$[with dimension $0$], the lines through the origin[with dimension $1$] and $\mathbf{R}^2$[with dimension $2$] itself.

Same idea will give you the subspaces for $\mathbf{R}^3$.

Now to think of a subspace with dimension $n$ say, think like you need $n$ linearly independent vectors through $0$. So, for a line[$1$-dimensional] you need $1$ vector, for a plane[$2$-dimensional], you need $2$ linearly independent vectors through origin.