# Describe all the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> I know that all the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ are:
>
> - Zero subspace.
> - Lines passing through origin.
> - Planes passing through origin.
> - $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ itself.
>
> But how to prove these are the only subspaces ?

I tried in the following way:

If subspace $S$ is zero, then done. So, assume a non zero element $(x,y,x) \in S $, then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, ~ \alpha(x,y,z) \in S.$ Now I need to prove that set $$ S= \lbrace \alpha(x,y,z) : \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace  $$ will be line passing through origin and if there exist an element $
(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1}) \ne \alpha(x,y,z) $, then we can generate plane passing through origin otherwise $\mathbb{R}^{3}.$

Comment: What can be the dimension of a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Comment: @Mark zero, one , two or three.

Comment: Yes, exactly. A subspace of dimension $1$ is a line, a subspace of dimension $2$ is a plane. Obviously they pass through the origin since a vector space must contain a zero vector.

Comment: See also the related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2988171/505767).

Comment: But $S$, as you have defined it, is never a plane: it is always a line (unless $x=y=z=0$). Can you see how to generate a plane? _Hint_: how many dimensions does a plane have?

Comment: @gimusi I read the answer carefully, but the way I am trying can provide any answer or not ?

Comment: @TonyK Ok, you want to say we need two linearly independent vectors for this purpose.

Comment: @ManojKumar They must pass through the origin and each component must be linear then we have that is $(at,bt,ct)$ or $(at+bu,ct+du,et+fu)$ with $t,u\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @Manoj: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have considered all the possible dimensions contained in $\mathbb{R^3}$ therefore there is not any other subspace to be considered.

It's a [proof by exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion).

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of a linear subspace $F$ of a vectorial space is lower or equal to the dimension of the space itself $E$.

Here, $\dim E = \dim \mathbb R^3=3$. Hence the dimensions of the subspaces belong to $\{0,1,2,3\}$. As subspaces of dimension $1$ are called lines and of dimension $2$ are called planes, you get the result,